# Problems converting mySQL_pconnect to mySQLi_connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I recently added an *SSL certificate* to my website and once it activated I got the following error when trying to view pages which are behind the login wall:

> Warning: mysql_pconnect(): Access denied for user 'refini14_admin'@'70.39.144.73' (using password: YES) in /home/refini14/public_html/Connections/Database.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: Access denied for user 'refini14_admin'@'70.39.144.73' (using password: YES) in /home/refini14/public_html/Connections/Database.php on line 9

My hosting company's support has told me that this is because `mysql_pconnect` is not supported in current versions of php and that I should modify it to use a different sql connection method.

I have tried to modify my database connection file to connect using *mysqli* however am still getting errors. This is the code I am currently using to connect (I have replaced some details with *):

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_Database = "******";
$database_Database = "refini14_db";
$username_Database = "refini14_admin";
$password_Database = "*******";
$Database = mysqli_connect($hostname_Database, $username_Database, $password_Database) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

I have only made modifications to line 9 as per the error message and have changed `mysql_pconnect` to `mysql_connect`. I am still getting the following error relating to `mysqli_error()`:

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/refini14/public_html/Connections/Database.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: in /home/refini14/public_html/Connections/Database.php on line 9

I am not experienced in mySQL and do not know how to resolve this error. Modifications I have made to `mysqli_error()` have not resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add your value and try:

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: I have tried your edit but now get the following error message: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'refini14_admin'@'70.39.144.73' (using password: YES) in /home/refini14/public_html/Connections/Database.php on line 9

Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/refini14/public_html/login.php on line 64

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/refini14/public_html/login.php on line 66

Comment: I edit the code. you insert your value. And again not try that means your username and password wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_error()` needs your connection variable i.e. `$Database` as a parameter so try it like this -

```
$Database = mysqli_connect($hostname_Database, $username_Database, $password_Database) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($Database),E_USER_ERROR);
```

instead of this -

```
$Database = mysqli_connect($hostname_Database, $username_Database, $password_Database) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```